# An error when install R package forecast on AWS instance

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

> install.packages('forecast')

Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/forecast_5.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 150965 bytes (147 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 147 Kb

installing *source* package ‘forecast’ ...
package ‘forecast’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
 libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c calcBATS.cpp -o calcBATS.o

In file included from calcBATS.cpp:1:0:
**calcBATS.h:36:27: fatal error: RcppArmadillo.h: No such file or directory**

#include 
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [calcBATS.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘forecast’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/forecast’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpJRX18M/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Can someone help me figure out this problem? I guess I am missing the RcppArmadillo package or it's not in the system path.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a missing package dependence, RcppArmadillo.

```
install.packages("RcppArmadillo")
```

Then:

```
install.packages('forecast')
```

Answer (score 0):

add within your lifecycle configuration

```
conda install -y -c r r-forecast
```